# How to filter positives negatives in pairs since they cancels out each other after grouping on Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataFrame as below. I am grouping on 3 columns of the dataframe:

1. `Cat1` (The values of Cat1 can be for example: A, B, C)
2. `Cat2` (The values of Cat2 can be for example: N, M, O)
3. `AbsOfTranAmt` - `AbsOfTranAmt` is the absolute value of `TranAmt`.

There are 3 groups in the dataframe below after grouping on `Cat1`, `Cat2` and `AbsOfTranAmt`.
I need the records back which don't add up to Zero in `TranAmt` (this is dollar amount column). Delete the records which cancels out.

```
Cat1 Cat2 AbsOfTranAmt TranAmt
  A   N     10           10
  A   N     10          -10
  A   N     10           10
  A   N     20           20
  A   N     20          -20
  A   N     30          -30
  A   N     30           30
  A   N     30          -30
  A   N     30          -30
  A   N     30          -30
```

Output Dataframe Should be:

```
Cat1 Cat2 AbsOfTranAmt TranAmt
  A   N     10           10
  A   N     30          -30
  A   N     30          -30
  A   N     30          -30
```

This is another Sample data:

```
Cat1  Cat2 AbsOfTranAmt TranAmt  
 A  N   25  25  
 A  N   25  25  
 A  N   25  25  
 A  P   25  -25  
 A  P   25  -25  
 A  P   25  25  
 A  P   25  -25  
 A  P   25  25  
 A  P   25  25  
 A  O   25  25  
 A  N   25  -25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to "count" the number of transactions for each triplet of [Cat1, Cat2, abs(TranAmt)]. A positive transaction increases the counter, a negative transaction decreases the counter.

Assume the data is stored in a dataframe called `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat1':['A']*10,
                   'Cat2':['N']*10,
                   'AbsOfTranAmt':[10,10,10,20,20,30,30,30,30,30],
                   'TranAmt':[10,-10,10,20,-20,-30,30,-30,-30,-30]})
```

**Solution 1: using a dictionary**

It is useful to define a function that returns the sign of a number:

```
def sign(x):
    return (x>0) - (x<0)
```

"Count" transactions:

```
counts = {}
for _,trans in df.iterrows():
    key = (trans['Cat1'],trans['Cat2'],abs(trans['TranAmt']))
    counts[key] = counts.get(key,0) + sign(trans['TranAmt'])
```

Cast results back to original format:

```
# get list of unmatched transactions
unmatched = []
for k,v in counts.items():
    unmatched += [(k[0],k[1],sign(v)*k[2])]*abs(v)

# cast to DataFrame and create AbsOfTranAmt
df_unmatched = pd.DataFrame(unmatched,columns=['Cat1','Cat2','TranAmt'])
df_unmatched['AbsOfTranAmt'] = df_unmatched['TranAmt'].abs()
```

Note that I deliberately chose not to use the values in `df['AbsOfTranAmt']`. This column seems redundant to me since it does not contain any information beyond `df['TranAmt']`.

**Solution 2: using groupby**

We again need a sign function, this time for a series:

```
def sign(series):
    return (series > 0).astype(int) - (series < 0).astype(int)
```

"Count" transactions:

```
df['count'] = sign(df['TranAmt'])
counts = df.groupby(['Cat1','Cat2','AbsOfTranAmt'])['count'].sum()
```

Cast results back to original format:

```
# get dataframe of unmatched transactions
df_unmatched = []
for _,count in counts.reset_index().iterrows():
    df_unmatched += [count]*abs(count['count'])

df_unmatched = pd.concat(df_unmatched,axis=1).T

# bring back to original format
df_unmatched['TranAmt'] = df_unmatched['AbsOfTranAmt']*sign(df_unmatched['count'])
df_unmatched.drop('count',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Edit 1: added a groupby solution that follows the same logic

Edit 2: changed some column names

Comment: Thank you very much JuilettVictor!!! I have used the Solution 1 Using Dictionary to solve my problem. I used this Solution 1 since I have other date columns in this dataframe to be added which are redundant to solve the original problem. But We want those extra 5 columns too which come with the original dataframe. With my basic knowledge of Python , I preferred solution 1 so that I can recreate the original dataframe by adding it in the "counts dictionary" keys. This solution worked on the dataframe, Thank you very much , this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to avoid too much iteration but some is needed at the end, though there could be better ways to achieve this (df contains the initial example data):

```
summary = df.groupby(['Cat1','Cat2','TranAmt']).count().reset_index()

summary['Count'] = summary.apply(lambda row: row['AbsofTranAmt'] if row['TranAmt'] > 0 else row['AbsofTranAmt'] * -1,axis=1)

summary['AbsofTranAmt'] = summary.apply(lambda row: row['TranAmt'] if row['TranAmt'] > 0 else row['TranAmt'] * -1,axis=1)

summary = summary.groupby(['Cat1','Cat2','AbsofTranAmt']).sum().reset_index()

summary['TranAmt'] = summary.apply(lambda row: row['AbsofTranAmt'] if row['Count'] > 0 else row['AbsofTranAmt'] * -1,axis=1)

print(summary)
```

This will give you

```
  Cat1 Cat2  AbsofTranAmt  TranAmt  Count
0    A    N            10       10      1
2    A    N            30      -30     -3
```

You can then use this to recreate the resulting dataframe

```
results = []

for r in summary.to_dict('records'):
    count = abs(r.pop('Count'))
    results += [r]*count

result_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

print(result_df)
```

Giving you:

```
 AbsofTranAmt Cat1 Cat2  TranAmt
0            10    A    N       10
1            30    A    N      -30
2            30    A    N      -30
3            30    A    N      -30
```

Comment: Thank you very much RBowen!!! I appreciate your time looking to find solution to my problem.